# Incorrect server response code - a non-404 is being reported as a 404

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, response

I'm trying to debug a WordPress video player theme which is using this standard AJAX request to populate a list of videos in a category:

```
function getdata(What) {
try {
    xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest():
    new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
catch (e) {}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = ScreenWrite; 
xmlhttp.open("GET", What, true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
return false;
```

}

The request goes to this page, with a dynamic ID parameter:
http://www.hisfameministries.com/wp-content/themes/Video/list.php?id=44

If you visit that page, the list shows up fine, but when you try it on the live site, the server responds with the requested data, but says it's a 404! Since it's an error, the AJAX request fails to load the data onto the page (or so I assume).

Here's the live site, for reference:
http://www.hisfameministries.com/sermons/

UPDATE:
Here's list.php, as requested: http://pastie.org/1270724

Comment: The URL you provided actually responds with HTTP 404 Response Code (even though browsers will display the page anyway). Your problem comes from the Wordpress end. It should be fixed there, not on the client's end.

Comment: Contrary to @netcoder's comments it seems like your `list.php` is a standalone file in your theme and not a WordPress file so I don't think it is WordPress causing the problem although the only way to tell would be for you to update your question and post the source of `list.php`; can you do that?

Comment: I found a temporary fix, but I don't feel too good about it. The ajax request was checking for server status of 200 before populating the list with the fetched data. I removed that check and it's working again.

Comment: Did you find the solution, i'm facing the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for people having the same problem (just spend a few hours)
Make sure the path to the file you include is correct;

```
<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
```

Isf so, add a header 200 status right after it.

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php');
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
```